# Dominant morphism that is not an open immersion between two birational varieties?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are affine varieties over an algebraically closed field such that $X$ and $Y$ are birationally equivalent. Furthermore, suppose we have a dominant morphism $\varphi: X \to Y$ which induces the birational equivalence of $X$ and $Y$. My question: is $\varphi$ necessarily an open immersion (i.e. the image is open and $\varphi$ is an isomorphism onto its image?

Comment: What if you take the normalization of a cuspidal cubic or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hoot is precisely right.

See for example: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46/what-is-the-universal-property-of-normalization

(Normalization of varieties is both birational and dominant)

As an example you can try to work out the normalization of a nodal cubic $y^2 = x^3 - x^2$ with affine ring $A := k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3+x^2)$. To normalize you have to adjoin $y/x$ to $A$, where $y/x$ satisfies $(y/x)^2 = x-1$. From this, you can compute: $x = (y/x)^2+1$, and hence $y = (y/x)^3 + (y/x)$, and so you find that by adjoining $y/x$, you get:
$$A[y/x] = k[y/x]\cong k[t]$$
Thus, the normalization of Spec $A$ is just the affine line $k[t]$, and the normalization map is given by the inclusion $k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3+x^2)\hookrightarrow k[t]$ sending $x\mapsto t^2+1$ and $y\mapsto t^3+t^2$. You can show the map is birational by showing that upon inverting $x$ in $A$ (equivalently, removing the node), the map becomes an isomorphism.